# How to change an iteration to recursion and vice-versa

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to change a function from iteration to recursion.

Here is the function:

```py
def differences(values):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(values) - 1):
        result.append(values [i+1] - values[i])
    return result

def palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <=1:
        return True
    if word[0] != word[-1]:
        return False
    return palindrome(word[1:-1])
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
differences list =
  if list has < 2 elements result is empty list
  otherwise, 
      list = first, second, *rest
      result is [second - first] + differences([second, *rest])
```

Implementing this in python, you can elegantly use the new [`match`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) statement.

Iteration:

```
palindrome str = 
   first = 0, last = len(str) - 1
   while first < last
       if str[first] != str[last] return false
       first++, last--
   return true
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function could be made recursive as follows:

```
def differences2(values, i = 1, res = []):
    if i < len(values):
        res.append(values[i] - values[i-1])
        return differences2(values, i + 1, res)
    else:
        return res
```

The second could be made iterative like this:

```
def palindrome2(word):
    pointer = 0
    while 2 * pointer + 1 <= len(word):
        if word[pointer] != word[-pointer-1]:
            return False
        pointer += 1
    return True
```

The recursive implementation of this can be very compact:

```
def palindrome(word, i = 0):
    if 2 * i + 1 <= len(word):
        return False if word[i] != word[-i-1] else palindrome(word, i = i + 1)
    return True
```

As a side note: in general, while very elegant, I am always a little bit worried in implementing recursive solutions in Python - iterative one are more readable and robust (again, those are my 2 cents).